# How many numbers are possible from $a^x b^y c^z$?

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, permutations, combinations

How to calculate total nos of possible value made from given numbers.

e.g. : $2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1$ . There $2$ , $3$ , $5$ , $2\cdot2$ , $2\cdot3$ , $2\cdot5$ , $3\cdot5$ , $2\cdot2\cdot3$ , $2\cdot2\cdot5$ , $2\cdot3\cdot5$ and $2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot5$ total $11$ possible values.

See $2\cdot3$ and $3\cdot2$ are count as same.

And you can use every digit max as their power times means in given example $2$ can be use max twice in any solution.

I trying to figure out this for $x_1^{y_1} \cdot x_2^{y_2} \cdot \cdots x_n^{y_n}$. Can anyone give solution.

All the base numbers here are primes $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ and $a$,$b$,$c$ are primes.

Can help me for a,b,c or if possible $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number $n \in \mathbf N$, has the prime decomposition $n = \prod_p p^{\nu_p(n)}$, where all but finitely many of the exponents $\nu_p(n)$ are zero, the number of divisors of $n$ is given by 
$$ \tau(n) = \prod_p \bigl(\nu_p(n) + 1 \bigr) $$
as each divisor $m$ of $n$ has $\nu_p(m) \le \nu_p(n)$ for all $p$, hence for each $p$ we have the $\nu_p(n) + 1$ choices $0, \ldots, \nu_p(n)$ for $\nu_p(m)$.

Or otherwise: The number of divisors of $\prod_i x_i^{y_i}$ is $\prod_i (y_i + 1) $.

Answer (score 0):

All products $2^i3^j5^k$ for different $i,j,k$ are distinct, and the exponents can take $3,2$ and $2$ values respectively, for a total count of $3\cdot2\cdot2=12$. (You get $11$ because you didn't count $2^03^05^0$.)

For arbitrary $x,y,z$, the count is $(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)$.

---

If $a,b,c$ aren't primes, you can turn them to their prime decomposition. For example

$$2^x5^y6^z=2^x5^y2^z3^z=2^{x+z}3^z5^y$$

and likewise, the count is $(x+z+1)(z+1)(y+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

For a number in the form

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}x_k^{y_k}$$

Observe that one can obtain a factor of it by choosing a degree for different prime factors. For example $2^3*3^4*5^2$, a factor of it would have degree less than or equal to the original number. Like $2^2*3^1*5^2$, here $2<3$,   $1<3$,   $2=2$.

So for a prime factor $x_k$, we have $y_k+1$ choices because we can choose not to have any power of factor of it (i.e. power 0). And we make independent choices over all prime factors

So the total number of prime factors

$$\prod_{k=1}^n (1+y_k)$$

Comment: @PoojanPatel You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you how to do it for two numbers and then you can figure out the rest.

$2^33^4$ would look like this

\begin{array}{lllll}
       &3    &33    &333    &3333 \\
  2    &23   &233   &2333   &23333 \\
  22   &223  &2233  &22333  &223333 \\
  222  &2223 &22233 &222333 &2223333 \\
\end{array}

So you can make $(3+1)(4+1) - 1 = 19$ numbers.

With $A^aB^bC^c$, you can make $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) -1$ numbers.

For example, with $2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1$, you can make 
$(2+1)(1+1)(1+1)-1 =11$ numbers.

And so on...